# Select date range from sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I really need your help.
I have problem getting values from database. I have two `editTexts` and one `Button`. When I insert dates and press `Button`  my table opens without data. How can I get for my database to read those `editText` values?

My code:

```
String val1=minDate.getText().toString();

String val2=maxDate.getText().toString();

Cursor c=database.rawQuery("SELECT * from  TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '"+ val1+"'  AND '"+ val2+"' ", null);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you please explain exactly what yo u need?

Comment: I have table where is column date, I want to user to be able to choose  maxdate and  mindate(range) he wants to see data.

Comment: Then your query should work, What problem you facing in it

Comment: My table opens with column names but it is empty without any data to show, when my query was just to select data from table it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your table? try without Where condition and make sure you have data in your table also , please show table structure
You can also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809421/1881611

Comment: Yes I do have data in my table, it all shows when I dont use range.

Comment: tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date")));            tableRow.addView(textView1);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            c.moveToNext() ;
        }
        setContentView(tableLayout);
        database.close();

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809421/1881611 ???

Comment: yes I did, It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

To avoid SQL injection, never add parameter to query by concatenating values, To create a query please refer to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Security tip:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#ContentProviders

How date are stored in your table ? Which format ?
When you add parameter to your query format must be the same.
If you want to use BETWEEN key word, date must be stored in this format: year-month-date to be sorted by SQLite.

**Update 1**

You're right change date format to yyyy-mm-dd
You parameters in your query must have same format, of course.
Put query in variable and log it before, as this:

```
String query = "SELECT * from  TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '"+ val1+"'  AND '"+ val2+"' ";
Log.d("MyQuery", query);
Cursor c=database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Search in logcat TAG "MyQuery" and post value of query

Comment: I think that is my problem because I have date format dd-mm-yyyy in my table.

Comment: okey. But is there a possibility for query to accept different forms of data, we use format dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: If you want to use BETWEEN: no

Comment: Can you please help me again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005670/scrollview-with-tablelayout-programmatically-java

Answer (score 1):

Now replace your code with below and let me know what you got in Logs

```
 Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * from  TABLE WHERE DATE >='"+val1+ "' AND <= '"+val2+ "'", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                Log.i("cursor_Data",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date")));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

If above not work for you then please post your TABLE Structure?